# Solving QGIS inconsistency between file names

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'll describe my particular case but I'm sure it's a more general problem. I'm using the r.horizon plugin (GRASS 7.4) in QGIS 3.8.3, which should produce an output raster file for every direction I've specified (from angle 0=East to 180=West, for example). The problem is I don't get all the outputs I should, only the ones for angles >100.
Apparently the software begins the calculations and creates all the files, naming the outputs:

```
outputda04053511ae49fa9d98db11bc54f4ac_000
outputda04053511ae49fa9d98db11bc54f4ac_090
outputda04053511ae49fa9d98db11bc54f4ac_180
```

But later when the software is creating layers based on these files, it does a search for:

```
outputda04053511ae49fa9d98db11bc54f4ac_0
outputda04053511ae49fa9d98db11bc54f4ac_90
outputda04053511ae49fa9d98db11bc54f4ac_180
```

How do I solve this inconsistency between the name the software gave the files, and the name it uses to retrieve them and create the layers?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. You should include the exact versions of software in the question

Comment: Thanks Vince for the warning and changes in format.

Comment: Do you think it is a r.horizon problem or a QGIS processing interface problem?

Comment: markusN It looks like a problem with the r.horizon script. Maybe other GRASS plugins have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. I couldn't fix what seems to be a bug but at least I managed to get the output for azimuth <100°.
In case anyone is interested, this is what I did. I took my DEM raster to ArcGIS, used the tool "mirror" and took this reversed layer to QGIS where I used it as input for the r.horizon tool. This allowed me to get the output for azimuth 0° (which in the reversed image became 180°) and for azimuth 45° (which became 135° in the reversed DEM). I took these output layers back to ArcGIS and used the "mirror" tool again.
I repeated the whole process but this time using the "flip" tool in ArcGIS (which allowed me to get the r.horizon output for azimuth 90°, which became 270° in the flipped version).
Hope this is useful to someone out there.